# Inequalities between $\text{class}(G)$ and $\text{rank}(G/[G,G])$ for f.g. nilpotent $G$

Tags: group-theory, nilpotence, finitely-generated

Let $G$ be a finitely generated nilpotent group of class $c$. Let $r=\text{rank}(G/[G,G])$ (i.e., the number of infinite cyclic summands of $G/[G,G]$).

Are there inequalities relating $c$ and $r$? (if so, are they tight?)

**EDIT**: There is a simple answer in the comments below.

Comment: No, there are no such inequalities. $c$ and $r$ can take values with $c \ge 1$ and $r \ge 0$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Do you mean that every pair $(c,r)$ with $c\geq 1$ and $r\geq 0$ is realized by some finitely generated nilpotent group $G$?

Comment: Yes. Consider the [free nilpotent group pf class $c$ and rank $r$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Free_nilpotent_group).

Comment: Yes that's what I meant.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: I don't understand how this realizes every pair $(c,r)$. How do you realize a given pair $(c,r)$? For example, in the notation of the page you linked to, if you take $n=1$, you get the group $\mathbb{Z}$ no matter what value you choose for $c$, don't you?

Comment: @DerekHolt: How? See my reply to Andreas's comment.

Comment: @NathanRikard, you are quite right, sorry. One needs $r > 1$ to get all values of $c$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: I see. It is not immediate to me why for $r>1$ you get class exactly $c$. One way to show it would be to construct a nilpotent group with class $c$ and rank at most $r$. Using unipotent integer matrices, I can do it if $r$ is large enough with respect to $c$, but I don't know about small values of $r$.

Comment: @NathanRikard, [the theory of basic commutators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_collecting_process) turns handy here.

Comment: I still claim that you can do it for all $c \ge 1$ and all  $r \ge 0$. Think about it!

Comment: @DerekHolt: Aha! $\mathbb{Z}^r \times UT(c+1,\mathbb{F}_2)$ !

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of ${\mathbb Z}^r \times D_{2^{c+1}}$, where $D_{2n}$ denotes the dihedral group of order $2n$.

Answer (score 0):

Groups of maximal class are an interesting source of examples.

[N. Blackburn](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485889035) has described among others the metabelian $p$-groups of maximal class, for $p > 3$. These are two-generated, and have arbitrarily large class. They can also be described handily with a modicum of number theory, see for instance the book

> C.R. Leedham-Green and S. McKay, The structure of groups of prime power order.

The [theory of basic commutators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_collecting_process) allows one to use free nilpotent groups as rather general examples.